# JavaScript : Output now shown as expected

Tags: javascript

How to to show "New Way" in `h1`, and "To do that way" in `h2`? My Output: "To do that way" in `h1` and "The Good Way" in `h2` is not expected.

```js
function init() {
  var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
  planet.innerHTML="New Way";
  document.getElementById("hard");
  planet.innerHTML="To do that way"
}
window.onload=init;
```

```html
<h1 id="greenplanet">The Great Planet</h1>
<h2 id="hard">The Good way</h2>
```

Comment: My Output:  To do that way (h1)  then The Good Way(h2) === not expected

Comment: You are adding text again in h1, so do this - `var checkthis = document.getElementById("hard"); checkthis.innerHTML="To do that way"`

Answer (score 0):

you are adding  'New Way' in `#greenplanet` and then replacing it with 'To do that way', you need to add it to `#hard`. you can do something like this:

```js
function init() {
  var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
  planet.innerHTML="New Way";;
  
document.getElementById("hard").innerHTML="To do that way"
}
window.onload=init;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="greenplanet">The Great Planet</h1>
  <h2 id="hard">The Good way</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't reassign planet var in 3rd line of your function.

BTW you don't inject HTML so change element.innerHTML to element.innerText or element.textContent

Comment: FYI, `innerText` and `textContent` are not alternative, only `textContent` is a standard property.

Comment: I know that there are differences between innerText and textContent however in this case IMHO each of them  would be better than using innerHTML. Both innerText and textContent are supported by all most important browsers. see browser compability section on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Comment: Looks like FF has adapted `innerText` too, though it still isn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

// correct your init() as below :

```
function init() {
  var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
  planet.innerHTML="New Way";
 var planet1 = document.getElementById("hard");
  planet1.innerHTML="To do that way"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reassign new div with "hard" id to planet variable in order to make your code work

```js
function init() {
  var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
  planet.innerHTML="New Way";
  planet = document.getElementById("hard");
  planet.innerHTML="To do that way"
}
window.onload=init;
```

```html
<h1 id="greenplanet">The Great Planet</h1>
<h2 id="hard">The Good way</h2>
```